# How to run a script that needs arguments with 7 optional and 5 COMPULSARY on Mac OS?

Tags: bash, arguments, parameter-passing, optional-arguments

How do I run my script with 5 Compulsory arguments and 7 optional ones.
Eg:

```
$ myscript -k "path" -o "somenumber" -n "path" -o "path" <noarg> "path"
```

This is must. It's fine if the script is run like this. The result will be obtained.

BUT, IF I want to run it with optional ones like:

```
$ myscript -e -k "path" -o "somenumber" -m "path" -o "path" <noarg> "path" -n "someword" -b "someIDLike abc.lpk.pou" -x "number"
```

The arguments -e, -m, -b and -x are optional.
How do I do this? Please do help. Thanks.

Comment: `How do I do this?` Depends on how the `myscript` handles arguments. Ask `myscript`.

Comment: Options shoud be optional anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way of parsing command line arguments in bash is to use the builtin command `getopts`. Bash treats the arguments to a script as positional and numbers them in ascending order from left to right, and there is another command that makes it easy to systematically move through them: `shift`. The usual was to construct the argument parsing code is to combine `getopts` and `shift` in a `while` loop, like this:

```
while getopts 'lhp:' OPTION; do
  case "$OPTION" in
    l)
      long=1
      ;;

    h)
      echo "you need some help" >&2
      echo "Try this: $(basename $0) [-l] [-h] [-p my_val]" >&2
      ;;

    p)
      p_val="$OPTARG"
      ;;
    ?)
      echo "ummmm..." >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
shift "$(($OPTIND-1))"
```

[This](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-use-getopts-to-parse-a-script-options) is a good overview.

From the man page:

> getopts: getopts optstring name [arg]
>
> Getopts is used by shell procedures to parse positional parameters.
>
> OPTSTRING contains the option letters to be recognized; if a letter
> is followed by a colon, the option is expected to have an argument,
> which should be separated from it by white space.
>
> Each time it is invoked, getopts will place the next option in the
> shell variable $name, initializing name if it does not exist, and
> the index of the next argument to be processed into the shell
> variable OPTIND.  OPTIND is initialized to 1 each time the shell or
> a shell script is invoked.  When an option requires an argument,
> getopts places that argument into the shell variable OPTARG.

To enforce the rule that certain arguments are mandatory, add some additional logic after the loop to verify that all the required arguments were actually provided. For example, in the above, we could say that `l` is mandatory, and check for it like this:

```
if [ -z $long ]; then
  echo "you didn't provide 'l'"
  exit 1
fi
```

The `-z` switch to the `[` command will yield true of the argument is an empty string, and false if the argument is non-empty.